# Create hibernate entity with foreign key to existing record

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am using hibernate 4.3.8.  In a Java Spring web app and postgres db.

I have record A with two foreign keys to record B and C.

Record B already exists in the system.
Record C is new and will be added when I save record A.
Record A layout is such.

```
A.primaryKey
A.foreignKey to B.primaryKey (already exists in system)
A.foreignKey to C.primaryKey (new record)
A.feildX
```

How do I save record A?

Thanks for your help

Here is the entity classes.I am new to hibernate which explains the errors.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="atable")
public class Aclass {

    @Id
    @Column(name="arec_id")
    private String id;

    //Do not create a reference to the bclass in this object. however do write the bclass object with a foreign key reference back to this aclass object
?   @Transient
?    @OneToOne(cascade=?)
?    @JoinTable(name="btable",inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="brec_id"))
?   private Bclass bclass;

    //Create a reference to the cclass object in this record and write the cclass object as well
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="crec_foreign_key",referencedColumnName="crec_id")
    private Cclass cclass;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    private VoiceEngineModel voiceEngineModel;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="btable")
public class Bclass {

    @Id
    @Column(name="brec_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="aref")
    private String aref;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;


}

@Entity
@Table(name="ctable")
public class Cclass {

    @Id
    @Column(name="crec_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;


}
```

Comment: Post the source code for your entity classes as well as your persistence code, if you have it yet

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Very easy. Original code for Bclass was wrong. Sorry.

1. remove any reference to Bclass in Aclass
2. for Bclass modify the columns reference

   @Entity
   @Table(name="btable")
   public class Bclass {

   @Id
   @Column(name="brec_id")
   private String id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="aref")
   private Aclass aref;

   @Column(name="description")
   private String description;

   }